# Need Help In Sorting A Vector Of Objects

Tags: java, sorting, object, vector

```
public class Sorting {
    Vector<Talk> sorty(Vector <Talk> s) {
        Collections.sort(s);
        return s;
    }
}
```

I need to sort Objects of the class `Talk` but I keep getting the error of 
"Bound mismatch".

Talk Class is something like this:

```
public class Talk {
    String name;
    int duration;

    public int compareTo(Talk t) {
         int compare = t.duration;
         return this.duration - compare; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Talk` class needs to implement the `Comparable` interface if you want to sort lists containing it:

```
public class Talk implements Comparable<Talk> {
```

Note that it is not safe to compare `int` values by subtracting them from each other, unless you know that both values are only going to be positive (or not more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` apart, to be precise). The reason is that an `int` will overflow and incorrectly turn negative if the values are more apart than that. Doesn't happen a lot, but it's a difficult bug to trace if it does happen, so better to get yourself used to an alternative.

A better way to compare, which always works, is to call `Integer.compare(int, int)`:

```
public int compareTo(Talk t) {   
    return Integer.compare(duration, t.duration);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Talk does implement a `compareTo` method, but it doesn't implement the `Comparable` interface, which is where the compareTo should be overriden from.

Change your Talk to:

```
public class Talk implements Comparable{
    String name;
    int duration ;

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Object o) 
    {    Talk t = (Talk)o;
         int compare = t.duration;
         return this.duration - compare; 
     }
}
```

For me, I always prefer a fixed -1,0 or 1 return:

```
@Override
        public int compareTo(Object o) 
        {    Talk t = (Talk)o;
             int compare = t.duration;
             return this.duration == compare ? 0 : this duration > compare ? 1 : -1; 
         }
```

but this is not mandatory.

I would, however, recommend to reconsider the access modifiers of your variables. Usually, private variables are recommended over package visibility.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i can help you.

```
   public class TestSorting {

    /**
     * @Desc:
     *      
     * @param args
     *
     * @Author: luochao
     * @CreateTime: 2016年2月3日 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vector<Talk> vector = new Vector<Talk>();
        vector.add(new Talk("centos",3));
        vector.add(new Talk("linux",1));
        vector.add(new Talk("java",2));
    }

}

class Talk implements Comparable<Talk> {
    private String name;
    private int duration;
    public Talk(String name,int duration) {
        this.name = name;
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }



    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }



    public int getDuration() {
        return duration;
    }



    public void setDuration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Talk o) {
        int compare = o.duration;
        return -(this.duration - compare); 
    }
}
```

Comment: You should also explain what it is you did, not just provide copy-paste ready code.

Comment: i'm so awful sorry to hear that ,at the first time to see it ,I just want to relize his request without thinking any other thing.thanks a lot for you advice.

Comment: Basically, you just repeated the answers already provided, without the explanations.